# AsyncTask : return from interface callback in doInBackground

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I would need some help to figure out how to return a `doInBackground()` value in `AsyncTask` which code is an interface. Here is an example

```
         private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

                    public MyAsyncTask() {
                        super();
                        // do stuff
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... void) {

                     checkIfContentAvailable(new interfaceMediaAvailableToDownload() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(boolean resutl) {
                                    return result; //This must be doInBackground return value, not onSuccess which is Void
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onInternetError() {
                                return false; //This must be doInBackground return value, not onSuccess which is Void
                            }
                        };
                    }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                     if (result){
                        //Do stuff
                     }else{
                        //Do stuff
                     }



                }
        }
```

Obviously, this above code can't work because I don't know how to return `onSuccess()` value to `doInBackground()`.

I hope this is clear enough....

**EDIT**

Okay my bad, I thought it would have been more readable to hide MyInterface usage, but I realize through your answers it is not. So I completed the code to add more details.

Any idea please? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: why do you want `myInterface` ?

Comment: The instance of your "myInterface" created inside doInBackground method is unused

Comment: It will also not work because you are just creating an instance of myInterface. No code is run. What is puropose of myInerface? Why are you trying to use AsyncTask? It may no be good solution for your problem.

Comment: Yep sorry, I thought it would be cleaner not to fill with extra code, but of course my interface is used through a different code which is not the purpose here :-) !

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the object of the Mynterface in the place where you execute the `AsyncTask`.
2. Create a object reference of the MyInterface inside the `AsyncTask` ans set your interface object.
3. Then call the `onSuccess` method like below

   ```
   `
       private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        MyInteface myInterface;
        setMyInterface(MyInterface interface){this.myInterface = interface;}

                   public MyAsyncTask() {
                       super();
                       // do stuff
                   }

                   @Override
                   protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... void) {
                    this.myInterface.onSuccess(); // or call on failure if failure happened

                   }

         @Override
               protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
       //Do stuff with result


               }
       }
   ```

   `

**Use it like ...**

```
MyAsyncTask async = new MyAsyncTask();
async.setMyInterface(this);
async.execute();
```

Implement the interface in the place where your are executing.

This how you can do it.

Comment: Normally return the result in the doInBackground and in the postExecute call the interface method to communicate to the caller.